# How to filter html table data with criteria in perl

Tags: perl, html-table

I new in Perl. I would like to return the data from the html table below, for those order more than 5,000 for each customer and each product. What is the best method in PERL to retrieve the data ? A sample code is much appreciated.

**DATA**

```
<html>
    <table id="table-2">
    <col width= 16%><col width= 16%><col width= 16%><col width= 16%><thead> 

    <tr><th><a>Customer  </a></th><th>Product A Ordered </th><th>Product B Ordered </th><th>Product C Ordered </th> </thead></tr>

    </tr><tr>
    <td>JJJ</td>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>125,492</td>
    <td>243,422</td>

    </tr><tr>
    <td>TTT</td>
    <td>5,500</td>
    <td>103,258</td>
    <td>194,506</td>

    </tr><tr>
    <td>MMM</td>
    <td>1,000</td>
    <td>22,234</td>
    <td>48,916</td>

    </tr><tr>
    <td>NNN</td>
    <td>3,000</td>
    <td>4,991</td>
    <td>13,070</td>

    </tr><tr>
    <td>PPP</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>251</td>

</html>
```